# Fire LoadingRowDetails in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application, .net-6.0

I am working in WPF app
I have a TextBlock inside DataGrid RowDetails.
Here I bound Textbloc Text property to a viewmodel  property,
So I want to fire LoadingRowDetails event
By each click on a row
But actually it calls this event for each row just one time.
When i click first row it load the first row relevant value,
When i click second row it load the second row relevant value,
Then, when i click again the first row it load again the second row relevant value inside the first rowdetail.
Could any one help me to fire this event by every click in each row.

Comment: Please add your code so we can understand and help..

Comment: We need xaml to know what you are doing.